# Invalid Syntax with datetime module

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to do something which should be fairly simple with the datetime module:

```
import datetime

timenow = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print timenow

if timenow >= 00:00:00.00000 and <= 00:15:00.00000

    #do some processing here
```

I have chosen my time format based on the result of the 'print timenow' line however it is throwing up a syntax error at the second colon in the first time variable stated.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error is that Python doesn't know how to interpret `00:00:00.00000`. It's not a string, it's not a valid numeric literal (like `5` or `-3.6`) and it's not a variable name, function name or keyword. So Python's all like "WTF are you doing to me man?!", and falls over.

You need to be nicer to your Python. Give it some help with what you mean. You could make those things into strings `"00:00:00.00000"`, but then Python still doesn't know that there's special rules for ordering datetime strings - so when you came to do comparisons you might end up with problems.

The better solution is to never worry about how a time looks as a string - all you care about is that a time has hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds. In particular, you only seem to care about hours and minutes.

Try this:

```
min_time = datetime.time(0,0)
max_time = datetime.time(0,15)

if min_time <= timenow <= maxtime:
    print "Do stuff!"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
import datetime

timenow = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print "%s\n" % str(timenow)

if str(timenow) >= "00:00:00.00000" and str(timenow) <= "00:15:00.00000":
  print "True"
```

What was wrong with your code?

- *You cannot compare a datetype type to a string.*
- *When you use "and" in a if statement, you have to do another condition.*
- *At the end of the line whom the if statement is on, you forgot to add : which is a part of the python syntax.*
- *You did not put quotes around the value you wanted to compare the datetime with.*

To make sure you understand:

```
import datetime

timenow = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print timenow
# below u need to put 00:00:00.00000 in quotes.
if timenow >= 00:00:00.00000 and <= 00:15:00.00000 # you forgot to add : here
```

Just ask if you don't understand.

**EDIT:** Note that all objects can not be string-compared like this. Thanks to [Tom Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372812/tom-dalton) for pointing this out.

> "While this works, it might lead a newer user into thinking all objects can be string-compared like this, however it wont work the way you want for things like this: ("Dec 2013" < "Nov 2013") -> True" - **[Tom Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372812/tom-dalton)**

Comment: While this works, it might lead a newer user into thinking all objects can be string-compared like this, however it wont work *the way you want* for things like this: ("Dec 2013" < "Nov 2013") -> True

Comment: @TomDalton Very true. Didn't think of this as i wrote my answer. Updated my answer with this info. Thanks for pointing it out.